# Seaborn stacking bars in multiple countplots located within a subplot

Tags: python, seaborn

Is there a way to stack the bars in `countplot` so each bar contains two colors.

My code so far:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(15,13), sharex=True)
axes = axes.flatten()
object_bol = df.dtypes == 'object'
for ax, catplot in zip(axes, df.dtypes[object_bol].index):
    sns.countplot(y=catplot, data=df, ax=ax, hue = "Attrition")

plt.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

My current visualization is below along with the stacked graph I am looking to implement.

[image: Current Visualization]

[image: Stacked Bar]

Comment: Hi ksantana3. To help us help you could you please provide your data set or a section of it.

Answer (score 0):

[You can pass keyword arguments](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) to `plt.bar` from `seaborn.countplot`.

You can, therefore use the `bottom` argument. For example (using `plt.bar`):

```
 x = np.arange(0,11,1)
 y = x**2

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.bar(x, y, bottom=y)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

Gives:

[image: bar_plot_example]